# When playing skilled retreat do fighters need to be transported?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

The skilled retreat card reads

> Move all of your ships from the active system into an adjacent system that does not contain another player's ships; the space combat ends in a draw.
> Then, place a command token from your reinforcements in that system.

Do fighters count as ships for this card to move, or do they need to be picked up by a carrier in order to be carried to the new system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a skilled retreat, fighters **must** be moved regardless of ship capacity.  If there is not capacity for them after the move, you will lose them.  Note that moving the fighters is not only possible, it's required.

## Justification

All rules justifications here come from the [Rules Reference 2.0](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/51/55/51552c7f-c05c-445b-84bf-4b073456d008/ti10_pok_living_rules_reference_20_web.pdf)

First, fighters are ships.

> 76 SHIPS
>
> A ship is a unit type consisting of carriers, cruisers, dreadnoughts, destroyers, fighters, and war suns. Each race also has a unique flagship.

Given the card says "ships" and not "ships with a movement value", fighters are moved.  This qualifies as an "ability movement", the rules for which explicitly ignore movement value:

> 58.8 ABILITY MOVEMENT
>
> 58.9 If an ability moves a unit outside of the “Movement” step of a tactical action, players follow the rules specified by that ability; neither a unit’s move value nor the rules specified above apply.

However, once you have moved, the rules for capacity kick in and you need to remove extra units.  Note that there is an exemption for capacity during combat, but the card ends the combat in a draw once the move is completed.

> 16.3 If a player has more fighters and ground forces in the space
> area of a system than the total capacity of that player’s ships in
> that system, that player must remove the excess units.
>
> a) A player can choose which of their excess units to remove.
>
> b) Ground forces on planets do not count against capacity.
>
> c) A player’s fighters and ground forces do not count against capacity during combat. At the end of combat, any excess units are removed and returned to that player’s reinforcements

As a final point, the card requires you to move "all your ships", meaning fighters must move regardless of capacity.  This is important because if it didn't move all the fighters, the game could end up in an invalid state.  Ships from multiple players can't co-occupy a space area except during combat.  The card ends the space combat in a draw, so all ships (including fighters) from one side need to be out of the space area.  The following rule, while not specifically relevant to the situation, is the constraint that this card is trying to preserve:

> 78.9 Space combat ends when only one player—or neither player—
> has a ship in the space area of the active system.